# Respecting 0s when sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, integer

These 3 numbers (10000, 11000, 9000) sort in the wrong order. They should resolve to 9000, 10000, 11000.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_list)'s the w3 code that I'm referencing:

Is there anyway to rewire this to work with integers?

Comment: Strings or ints in JS?

Comment: `[10000, 11000, 9000].sort((a, b) => a - b);`

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort to your rescue!!

```
function bubble_Sort(a)
{
    var swapp;
    var n = a.length-1;
    var x=a;
    do {
        swapp = false;
        for (var i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] > x[i+1])
            {
               var temp = x[i];
               x[i] = x[i+1];
               x[i+1] = temp;
               swapp = true;
            }
        }
        n--;
    } while (swapp);
 return x; 
}

console.log(bubble_sort([10000, 11000, 9000]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.sort function:

```js
var test = [3,5,7,2,3,1];
console.log(test.sort());
//result : [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7]

//for descending
console.log(test.sort((a,b) => b-a));
//result : [7, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Please try the following: `[1,10,6,5].sort()` and carefully observe the result. For numeric ordering (as opposed to lexicographical ordering), you **always** need to provide a *sortFunc*

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the .toLowerCase() and wrap the check in parseInt() and it will work with the code you provided:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sort a HTML List Alphabetically</title>
<body>

<p>Click the button to sort the list alphabetically:</p>
<button onclick="sortList()">Sort</button>

<ul id="id01">
  <li>10000</li>
  <li>11000</li>
  <li>9000</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>

<script>
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("id01");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    // Loop through all list-items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
      if (parseInt(b[i].innerHTML) > parseInt(b[i + 1].innerHTML)) {
        /* if next item is alphabetically
        lower than current item, mark as a switch
        and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 0
for(var i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
    if(numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]){
        a = numbers[i+1];
        numbers[i+1] = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = a;
    }
}
```

This is called bubble sort or insert sort